# numpy matrix not functioning as intended

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This is my code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import math

populacao = 5
x_min = -10
x_max = 10
nbin = 4

def fitness(xy, populacao, resultado):

    fit = np.matrix(resultado)

    xy_fit = np.append(xy, fit.T, axis = 1)

    xy_fit_sorted = xy_fit[np.argsort(xy_fit[:,-1].T),:]
    return xy_fit_sorted


def codifica(x, x_min, x_max,n):
    x = float(x)
    xdec = round((x-x_min)/(x_max-x_min)*(2**n-1))
    xbin = int(bin(xdec)[2:])
    return(xbin)


xy = np.array([[1, 2],[3,4],[0,0],[-5,-1],[9,-2]])
resultado = np.array([5, 25, 0, 26, 85])

print(xy)
xy_fit_sorted = np.array(fitness(xy, populacao, resultado))
print(xy_fit_sorted)

parents = (xy_fit_sorted[:,:2])

print(parents)
```

the problem i'm having is that to select the 2 rows of "xy_fit_sorted", i'm doing this strange thing:

> parents = (xy_fit_sorted[:,:2])

Intead of what makes sense in my mind:

> parents = (xy_fit_sorted[:1,:])

it's like the whole matrix is in one line.

Comment: what's the shape and dtype of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what most of your code is doing, so here's just a guess: are you thrown off by the shape of `xy_fit_sorted` being `(1, 5, 3)`, having an extra zero axis?

That could be fixed e.g. by constructing `xy_fit` without the use of `np.matrix`:

```
xy_fit = np.append(xy, resultado[:, np.newaxis], axis=1)
```

Then `xy_fit_sorted` comes out with a shape of `(5, 3)`.

The underlying issue was that `np.matrix` is always a 2-D array. When indexing `xy_fit[...]` you intend to index with a vector. But using `np.matrix` for xy_fit, `xy_fit[:,-1].T` is not a vector, but a 2-D array as well (of shape (1,5)). This leads to `xy_fit_sorted` having an extra dimension as well.

Note that the numpy doc says about np.matrix anyhow:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. But could you explain to me what's the difference in what you did and what I was doing? I removed some unnecessary parts from de code too.

Comment: @JoãoVitorDegrandi I changed the answer to use `np.append`, like you were originally doing, just removing the `np.matrix` part. I tried giving an explanation as to what happens.